# Connecting to database in Express

Tags: node.js, express

### Trying to connect to database using Express

- I am new to Express(I have used NODEJS),
- I am trying to connect to database and display a simple JSON as the
  resultant output
- I tried the below code

---

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: "root",
        database: 'restaurant'
});

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function(err, rows, fields)

        {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        });

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Error::**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                 ^
ReferenceError: mysql is not defined
```

---

Error tells mysql module is absent, But i have installed mysql module using::

```
npm install mysql
```

Still no change in error
**Any ideas**

Comment: you're missing `mysql      = require('mysql')` in your module

Comment: `var mysql = require('mysql');` or `, mysql = require('mysql');` after deleting the previous `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `mysql` module.

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql');
```

But also you need to `connect()`:

```
connection.connect();
```

Before you start querying the database.

**All-together now for laziness:**

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'restaurant'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants', function(err, rows, fields)

    {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: What do you do when you have that `mysql.connection()` part in `app.js` but you need to query the database from other files?